# Updated Python produces an error when running a proved code (using anaconda)

Tags: python, anaconda

I hope somebody can help me, I'm experiencing an Error in a code that has been proved in the past. The only change that I did was to update anaconda by typing in the terminal:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

after the update, when I run my code I got:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Has anyone ever had this happen?

Comment: You should be more specific. Which library is throwing the error?

Comment: I 'd check if it didn't start to use entirely different python version (2 > 3 or viceversa)

Comment: Yes, code can break when you update libraries. It happens all the time.

Comment: I don't get it, Why does this happend?

Comment: Alright, I solved just by changing a float by an integer in a line where I use `.shift` Sorry for to be unspecific on this I still don't understand why occurs these kind of errors after an update. Thanks all!

Comment: This looks like an error in the NumPy package that used to be a warning. Probably you updated NumPy when you updated `anaconda`, and the warning became an error. However, without substantially more detail, it is impossible to be sure.